# django custom 404 not found page

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to create custom not found page. But, I can see only default django not found template. What I'm doing wrong ?

**notFound.html**

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load account socialaccount %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Page not found" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top:50px;opacity:0.90"> 
    <h1 class="text-center" style="color:#A12830">4+800:2</h1>
    <h3 class="text-center">Web page not found</h3>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Main menu</a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import (handler400, handler403, handler404, handler500)
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of your Python code? Where do you refer to the `notFound.html` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you first set **DEBUG=False** in your setting file. And you also need to change your html name to *404.html* and locate it in root directory of your project.